# Strange WPF Display in VB.Net App: All Window Properties Update Correctly, But Some Changes Not Displayed

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I’ve run across a VB threading and WPF display problem that has me baffled. I'm new to threading, but the thing is that my code executes exactly as expected; the problem is that the WPF controls it affects aren’t updated right. I’ve scoured the Internet for potential fixes but am still coming up empty-handed.

I’m trying to update a crude SplashScreenWindow in the Initialized sub of my MainWindow. There’s quite a bit of initialization code – most of which I’ve commented out here – so I want to let the user know what loading phase they’re in and provide a ProgressBar as a visual aid. The simple WPF code for these controls and the SplashScreenWindow appear at the end of this code sample, while the splash screen itself is referenced at Application scope. In the Initialized sub I make several synchronous calls to the splash screen’s Dispatcher.Invoke method, which is handled by the UpdateSplashScreenWindow delegate in the Application class. Some of these calls are made in the constructor of a TableClass class, which handles the creation of several dozen data classes one at a time, as directed in some code I’ve commented out.

I can verify at any breakpoint that the values of the ProgressBar and LoadingTextBox are updated exactly as I directed them to be. On the other hand, the display of the controls is normally updated just one time, after the first call to Dispatcher.Invoke; what I usually see is the SplashScreen frozen with a text message saying “Initializing Dataset” and a ProgressBar that’s only moved a smidge. Then there are no further updates until the Initialized code is done, the MainWindow opens and the SplashScreenWindow is disposed of. Yet if an error is caught in the Try…Catch, the progress bar and textbox will suddenly display the correct values. I can set breakpoints anywhere in the code – even in the WindowLoadingProgressBar_ValueChanged event in the SplashScreenWindow - and verify that at no point are the Text and Value properties set incorrectly. It gets even weirder though. As you can see in the UpdateSplashScreenWindow, I add the letter s to the title of the SplashScreenWindow at each pass, as a visual test. I see the title scrolling to the right across the top of the screen as expected, but the child controls below it are only updated once, although both are in the very same routine.

Calling InvalidateMeasure, InvalidateVisual and UpdateLayout on either the controls or their parent window are among the workarounds that have no effect. I don’t think it’s a threading problem, because the splash screen thread executes synchronously, as expected. Those seem to be the usual culprits in other references to WPF visual updating problems I’ve seen on the Web, but I think I’ve ruled them out. If anyone has any ideas, I’d appreciate some input.  I’m not too worried right now about tangential issues like whether the referencing the splash screen at Application scope is good design practice or not, or investigating other means of threading WPF windows, like BackgroundWorker. After getting this far and finally getting my code to work in theory, I’d like to figure out whatever’s preventing it from displaying right in practice, in case I or anyone else ever runs into the issue again.

```
Private Sub MainWindow_Initialized(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Initialized

        Try
            InFormLoadedBoolean = True

            Application.SplashScreenWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(New Application.UpdateSplashScreenDelegate(AddressOf Application.UpdateSplashScreenWindow), Application.SplashScreenWindow, "Initializing Datasets", 5)

 ‘set some dataset properties here
                Application.SplashScreenWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, New Application.UpdateSplashScreenDelegate(AddressOf Application.UpdateSplashScreenWindow), Application.SplashScreenWindow, "Initializing Data Classes", 5)

‘initialize several dozen data-bound classes here, one at a time
            Application.SplashScreenWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(New Application.UpdateSplashScreenDelegate(AddressOf Application.UpdateSplashScreenWindow), Application.SplashScreenWindow, "Initializing Control Resources", 5)

‘initialize a long list of WPF resources here
‘add some event handlers

Application.FormLoadedBoolean = True
        Catch MyException As Exception
            ErrorCheckerDebugVersion(MyException)
        End Try

Application.SplashScreenWindow.LoadingTextBox.Text = "Finished Loading"

        Me.Width = 1680
        Me.Height = 1050

        Application.SplashScreenWindow.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden
        Application.SplashScreenWindow = Nothing

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(TempName As String, TempViewSource As CollectionViewSource, FillOnInitializeBoolean As Boolean, TempDataGrid As DataGrid, TempPopup As Primitives.Popup, AdapterTypeNameString As String, TempDataRowTypeNameString As String)

‘do some initialization work for each data class here, all of which executes as expected

        Application.SplashScreenWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(New Application.UpdateSplashScreenDelegate(AddressOf Application.UpdateSplashScreenWindow), Application.SplashScreenWindow, "Initializing Data Classes", 20)

    End Sub

Class Application

    Friend Shared SplashScreenWindow As New DashboardApplication.SplashScreenWindow
    Public Delegate Sub UpdateSplashScreenDelegate(sender As SplashScreenWindow, LoadingTextBoxText As String, Amount As Int32)

    Public Shared Sub UpdateSplashScreenWindow(sender As SplashScreenWindow, LoadingTextBoxText As String, Amount As Int32)

        sender.WindowLoadingProgressBar.Value = sender.WindowLoadingProgressBar.Value + Amount
        sender.LoadingTextBox.Text = LoadingTextBoxText
        sender.Title = sender.Title + "s"
        If sender.IsActive = False Then sender.Show()
        sender.InvalidateVisual()
        sender.InvalidateMeasure()
        sender.WindowLoadingProgressBar.InvalidateVisual()
        sender.WindowLoadingProgressBar.InvalidateMeasure()

        sender.WindowLoadingProgressBar.UpdateLayout()
        sender.LoadingTextBox.UpdateLayout()
    End Sub

Public Class SplashScreenWindow
 Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded   
    End Sub

    Private Sub WindowLoadingProgressBar_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs(Of Double)) Handles WindowLoadingProgressBar.ValueChanged   
        WindowLoadingProgressBar.UpdateLayout()
        WindowLoadingProgressBar.InvalidateMeasure()
        WindowLoadingProgressBar.InvalidateVisual()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Could you please write a TL;DR version? I don't think anyone will have the patience to read your whole question ;)

Comment: Sorry, I figured it would help to provide as much detail as possible so that the problem was in context and we didn't end up rehashing stuff I'd already tried. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip Thomas, I cut out some of the extra detail and finally made the formatting a little more legible :)

Comment: I take it you mean asynchronously, but I'm not sure where you are instantiating your worker thread.

Comment: Actually, it's supposed to be synchronous, which updates the splash screen properties exactly when I want them to. For example, I create a single data class in the MainWindow, then the ProgressBar is immediately moved forward just a little bit, in an interleaved way. The behavior wasn't as predictable with asynch threading, so I switched. The debugger says it's doing exactly what I want it to, but some elements of the window don't display what their property values say they should. i.e if the ProgressBar is set to 45, it will display 5; the window title, however, is updated continuously.

Comment: Then I'm not sure why you are using Invoke. Anyway, a tip when using the progress bar is to set it to a higher value than you want, then drop it back.

Comment: Thanks Peter - Maybe I'm handling the threading aspect wrong, since I'm new to the topic. The reason I thought it might be something else is that from the debugger's standpoint, the values of the textbox and progressbar are both updated just when I want them to be using the code as is; they're just not displaying right. Yet changes to the window they're in are displayed correctly when altered by the same code on the same thread. I guess I'm looking for a way to force the controls to refresh their displays correctly

Comment: Ah, right, my mistake, I misunderstood your question. But it does sound like a threading issue. In order to update the display, the gui thread must have a message pump, and must be idle enough to pull items from it, so it sounds like your gui thread is busy doing something else.

Comment: Thanks - any ideas on how I can force the other window's controls to refresh? I thought by using Dispatcher.Invoke that the other window would be running on a separate thread and I wouldn't have this display problem with the constituent controls - especially since the title portion displays correctly with the code as it is. Using an asynchronous thread doesn't work, because the properties on the splash screen aren't updated in the same predictable order, i.e. in lockstep with the initialization code in the main window.

Comment: The GUI thread's message pump is idle enough that it updates the properties of the title bar, progressbar and textbox exactly when it should without fail, but in the case of the last two, it simply skips over the display part.

Comment: " I thought by using Dispatcher.Invoke that the other window would be running on a separate thread " - no, simply using Dispatcher.invoke does not automatically mean it's on another thread. You have to instantiate the thread yourself, either explicitly or by using a BackgroundWorker etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved this with the aid of two invaluable articles I found at other sites, Suchit Khanna's "Creating WPF window's on dedicated threads"  [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/suchit_84/creating-wpf-windows-on-dedicated-threads/ and Reed Copsey Jr.'s "Launching a WPF Window in a Separate Thread, Part 1" [link](http://reedcopsey.com/2011/11/28/launching-a-wpf-window-in-a-separate-thread-part-1/)

I basically got a baptism by fire with threading; apparently what I was trying to accomplish was actually a bit too advanced for a threading novice like me. Instead of calling a BackgroundWorker or other thread from my MainWindow and doing work there, as would normally be the case, I need to do the reverse and perform the work in the main thread, but display it in another. That required starting the other window in its own thread, which is explained in the two links above. They're written in C#, so I had to convert their code examples to VB and apply some other adaptations. I've posted it here in case anyone else runs into the same problem:

'I added the following code to the Application class to ensure that the SplashScreenWindow runs on its own dedicated thread

Imports System.Threading.SynchronizationContext
Friend Shared SplashScreenThread As System.Threading.Thread

```
Public Shared Sub StartSplashThread()

    SplashScreenThread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf ThreadWork)
    SplashScreenThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
    SplashScreenThread.IsBackground = True
    SplashScreenThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal
    SplashScreenThread.Start()

End Sub

Public Shared Sub ThreadWork()

    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(New System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherSynchronizationContext(System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher))

    SplashScreenWindow = New DashboardApplication.SplashScreenWindow
    SplashScreenWindow.Show()

    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
End Sub
```

'I also added this to the UpdateSplashScreenWindow routine in the Application class, which calls the SplashScreenWindow_Closed routine below, in the SplashScreenWindow. This keeps the thread from staying alive after the window's closed

```
    If LoadingTextBoxText = "Opening Main Window" Then
        SplashScreenWindow.Close()
        SplashScreenWindow = Nothing
    End If
```

Private Sub SplashScreenWindow_Closed(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Closed
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background)

```
End Sub
```